# How to remove the icon in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am getting this wired small g icon on my eclipse screen, How to remove these icon.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 'Show whitespace characters' enabled. There is a button on the toolbar to toggle this setting. It looks like:

[image]

You can also configure this is the Preferences in 'General > Text Editors' - the 'Show whitespace characters' option. You can also set which whitespace is shown there.